# Error when presenting ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem with presenting a ViewController. The Presented ViewController contains:
UIImageView
UIScrollView which contains a UICollectionView.

In the

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

I pass a value from the first to the second ViewController like this:

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = segue.destinationViewController;
secondVC.value = passValue;
```

When I launch the App and present the SecondViewController, everything works fine. If I go back to the first ViewController and then present the second ViewController again I get the following error message:

```
*** -[SecondViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x170224e0
```

Of course the App breaks.
What could that mean and how could I solve this. 
I already got much trouble with this problem and thank you for help.
Jannes

Comment: I see no reason why it is happening, all i can do is give you a suggestion, use this line `SecondViewController *secondVC = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;` inside `prepareForSegue`. Else add more code so we can figure out the issue.

Comment: You should get a stack trace showing where isKindOfClass is called

Comment: I wondered the same thing -- whether you needed to explicitly cast the destinationViewController to the specific type.

Comment: Turn on zombies in your build scheme.  It should give you a more useful error message.

Comment: Zombie Objects are enabled

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. It looks like `isKindOfClass` is being called in Apple's `[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]`